# MVC 2 routing question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to create a route that looks like this

> site.com/controller/{Param1}/{dbID}-{friendly-name}

and omit the default action index , and for the action edit to be at the end of the url like so

> site.com/controller/{Param1}/{dbID}-{friendly-name}/edit

routes are a bit confusing for me , so any help is appreciated , 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SomeRoute",
    "{controller}/{param1}/{dbID}-{friendlyName}/{action}",
    new 
    { 
        controller = "home", 
        action = "index",
        param1 = "CANNOT BE OPTIONAL",
        dbID = "SOME DEFAULT ID",
        friendlyName = "SOME DEFAULT FRIENDLY NAME"
    }
);
```

Comment: hm , if i request the page without the index action at the end , it doesn't load :(

Comment: its also important to put the default route at the bottom and the more specific routes at the top :)